# Trying to search a random access file using a string

Tags: c, file, search, io

I can search a random access file without any issues but the problem is I don't understand how it actually works.

Previously i searched a random access file using the method

```
 FILE fpnt = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb+");

 User tempUser = {"", "", 0, "", 0};
 printf("Enter the id number of the user to find\n");
 scanf("%d", idNum);
 fseek(fpnt, (idNum - )* sizeof(User), SEEK_SET);
 fread(&tempUser, sizeof(User), 1, fpnt) != EOF && found == 0;
```

I don't understand how this always finds the correct user when ass the offset isn't always necessarily the same as the ID i would assume. But the problem lies with when I'm trying to access files by using data other than integers.

for example, I'm trying to find users by their names which are strings. the method I use is the following:

```
 typedef enum tUserLevel {
     MANAGER = 1,
     CLERK = 0,
     NOTFOUND = 9001
 }level;


 typedef struct tUser {
     char userName[20];
     char password[20];
     level priviledgeLevel;
 }User;

do {
    fseek(fpnt, offSet * sizeof(User), SEEK_SET);
    if (fread(&tempUser, sizeof(User), 1, fpnt) == EOF)
        endOfFile = EOF;        
    rewind(fpnt);
    offSet++;
} while (endOfFile!=EOF && !strcmp(username, tempUser.userName));

if (endOfFile==EOF&& strcmp(username, tempUser.userName)) {
    printf("The User was not found\n");
    return noUser;

    //return noUser;
}
```

So what is supposed to happen is the file will check each user for the entered username (that's the variable called username) and compare the two and stop if both are correct. I'm not sure how this is actually looping though or if the offset affects the pointer in the file the way I want. What DOES happen is I'm always getting EOF so that portion of the code always run even after one read. I had 4 test users Is there a better way to search for these files by string so I can read them and edit them in the file or is this the best way and I'm messing it up somewhere?

Comment: `fseek` and `rewind` make no sense here. The code returns to the beginning of the file (rewind), and then immediately turns around and goes back to the exact same it was a moment ago (fseek). The two calls can be just removed.

Comment: When will `fread()` return EOF?

Comment: Zing, Offset is initialized to zero yes so it would start from the beginning and increment. I'm not sure if the pointer location was going to stay at the same positions between iterations so I offset it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is assuming that the file consists of fixed-length `User` records, arranged by id number, with no gaps. The record for id 1 would be at offset 0, and the record for id `N` would be at `(N - 1) * sizeof(User)`. If that's what the file actually contains, this is a reasonable assumption.

The code in the bottom part of your question seems to be suffering from an identity crisis. It can't figure out if records are sequential and ordered by id, or if the file needs to be searched by matching on `username`. It's an unworkable hybrid of two different lookup methods. You need to pick one method and go with it.

If the file is ordered by id and contains no gaps (and you're searching by id), you don't need to search in a `while` loop.

On the other hand, if the file is either unordered, or contains gaps, then it is necessary to search. In that case, then the `fseek` and `rewind` calls are not needed. Just start from the beginning of the file and read every record sequentially, one at a time, until you find the one matching the requested username.

Also, comparing the return value of `fread` with `EOF` is wrong. The `fread` function returns the number of items actually read. If the returned number is not equal to the number of items you specified in the call, then either there was a read error, or you've hit the end of file. The `EOF` constant is intended for use with functions like `fgetc` that return *character* values.

Comment: So if I repeatedly call fread() it will move the pointer through the file like fscanf() would?

Comment: Thanks. I now understand this. I should be reading it sequentially and comparing each read with the data inputted. As for what you mentioned with Gaps to ensure that I don't leave gaps I should assume I can just read sequentially until an empty struct, or "deleted struct" is found and overwrite that. And to actually edit the data I'll have to offset the pointer negatively by the size of the structs I'm writing. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Deeswoc By "gaps", I was referring to gaps in the sequence of id values within the file. Not gaps in the data where there is e.g., nothing but zeros or something like that. The point was that if you're looking up by id, and calculating the offset for that id in the file, then you're assuming that every id in the sequence up until that point exists in the file. For instance, if you're looking up id 5, but your file only contains records for ids 1,2, and 5, then how do you calculate the correct offset? Certainly not with `(id - 1) * sizeof(User)`.

Comment: @Deeswoc And of course this means that repeated ids cannot exist either, e.g., a file with records for ids 1,1,2,3,4,4,5. In that case, `(id - 1) * sizeof(User)` also gives an incorrect offset, even though there are no gaps.